# Merging two layers in keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I use concatenate function to merge two layers in Keras

```py
#Statistics pooling layer
h1=Lambda(stats_pool_mean,output_shape=(1,1500))(embedd)
h2=Lambda(stats_pool_std,output_shape=(1,1500))(embedd)
h=keras.layers.concatenate([h1,h2])   <---- Source of error
h=keras.layers.Reshape((1,3000))(h)
```

I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'layer'
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: I don't think this code has any error. The error must be due to rest of the code, that you haven't shown.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I fixed the bug. I should 've imprted either keras of keras.layers not both !